# Change the position of objects without messing code

Tags: html, css, translate

I have a website in English and now I wanted to translate it into Hebrew, the problem is that in Hebrew writing from right to left, there is software which I can open the old site and drag some items to the right and of course edit the text from English into Hebrew ?

In addition, I want to change the position of the buttons.

You could say I'm looking for a program that would give me the ability to alter the placement of site locations or edit the site without having to work directly in front of the code (`html` , `css`)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `* { direction: rtl; }`

Comment: What if I want to add a picture or anything ? There is no software to edit a site with no  messing with the code ? Just drag and drop

Comment: look into locale implementation

Comment: I see that [link](http://www.tweakandtrick.com/2011/03/javascript-tricks-edit-websites-in.html) but It not let me switch pictures only text.